# remove a select2 tags with specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I manipulated my select2 to accept equal tagged text, but with different value.
example: city-0, city-1, 2-city, city-3 ...

Now, I need to delete a specific tag (city-2)

[image]

**This code does not work for me, because *I create dynamically* equal texts ...**

```
    $(".select2-search-choice div").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === "Hawaii";
    }).parent().remove(":eq(0)");
```

Is there a command to get the tag index in select2 multi? Tks!

Comment: When creating the tags, can you set an id for the corresponding div? Then you could filter like:  return $(this).attr('id') === "city-2"; Of course this will work only if the values you are setting are unique.

Comment: I thought about it, tried to put an id to the div, but unfortunately I could not got it......... (ps. just now gave me an answer, but I can not see her anymore ... return $(this).data("tag") === "city-2"; ?)

Comment: How do I assign an ID to the corresponding div tag? Would solve for sure... :)

Comment: When you say you create dynamical equal text you can also assign an `id` to it right???

Comment: i can not do that .. because the text is the tag <option> that is independent of the tag which is in select2 ... she is within a div... =/

Comment: thought about it but does not work: $(this).select2("data")[2].remove(); $(this).select2("data")[2].id.remove();

Comment: Dear @Fabio are you have the key of the question you posted.Please share if you have.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $("#select").val(e.val.map(function(val){ 
       console.log(val); 
       return (val!="Hawaii")?val:""; }
  )).select2();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.